# sprintf: right-alignment of multiple formatters

Tags: c++, printf

Is there a way to right-align multiple formatters at once with `sprintf`?

Example:

```
|----------|
|      20 s|
|----------|
```

Given a space of 10 chars, I want to right-align all the formatters.
I'm able to use the pad options for single formatter, example:

```
sprintf(line, "%10s", "s");
```

Printing the content above left-aligned is simple:

```
sprintf(line, "%d %s", 20, "s");
```

Now, what if I want to right-align all the content `20 s` given the 10-char of space?
The only workaround that I know is to `sprintf` two times:

```
sprintf(content, "%d %s", 20, "s");
sprintf(line, "%10s", content);
```

Is there a more compact and elegant way to do this?

Comment: In a word, no. What you are already doing is about as compact as it gets with `sprintf()`. Is there a reason why you are not using `std::cout` instead?

Comment: I'm working on an MCU. The code fills the buffer that I have to send using a serial line.